# How to populate a group in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose-populate

I have this in my mongoose schema...with some group...

```js
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name                                : { type: String },
    offerings                   : [{ type: String }],
    cscPersonnel                : {
        salesExec                   : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        accountGM                   : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
},
    },
    netPromoterScore        : { type: Number }

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('clients', clientSchema);
```

I tried to populate reff dis way...I have also populated in ref (user as {path:'cscPersonnel'})

```js
function getOneById(id){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
console.log("im in get by id" +id);
    model
        .findOne({ _id: id })
        .populate({path:'cscPersonnel'})//one way
           /* 'cscPersonnel salesExec',   //second way
            'cscPersonnel accountGM', */
        .exec(function (err, item) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                deferred.reject(err);
            }
            else
                console.log(item);
                deferred.resolve(item);
        });

    return deferred.promise;
} // gentOneById method ends
```

but unfortunatly ended up with this error!!!!

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "_id"

```js
{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"_id\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "type": "ObjectId",
  "value": {
    "salesExec": "56cf5f09245f8a240b30693b",
    "accountGM": "56cf5f09245f8a240b30693b"
  },
  "path": "_id"
}
```

how to make it solve this issue.... *do help , thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one

```
model
    .findOne({ _id: id })
    .populate({path: 'cscPersonnel.salesExec'})
    .populate({path: 'cscPersonnel.accountGM'})
    .exec(function (err, item) {
```

Comment: @swatikiran, please ask another question for your new issue.